# Adding attributes to Wicket session

Tags: java, session, wicket

There is an implementation of WebSession, which supposed to store ID of logged user:

```
public class SecurityWebSession extends AuthenticatedWebSession {

    public SecurityWebSession(Request request) {
        super(request);
        bind();
    }

    ...

    @Override
    public boolean authenticate(String username, String password) {
        user = usersFacadeLocal.findByEmail(username);
        if (user != null) {
            try {
                boolean valid = PasswordHash.validatePassword(password, user.getPassword());
                if (valid) {
                   WebSession.get().setAttribute(USER_ID, user.getId());
                }
                return valid;
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                logger.error("Authenticate ERROR", ex);
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

However, when I access SecurityWebSession to get ID of logged user from WebPage class, it returns null. I came across that Session does not store values which were added from its body. But it perfectly stores values if set them from classes inherited from Wicket's WebPage.

I did not find any mention in documentation about this situation. How can I add to Session attributes from Session?

Answer (score 4):

Do you use Wicket 6.19.0 by chance?
If this is the case then you hit https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WICKET-5845. It is fixed in 6.20.0.
If this is not the case then please create a new ticket with a quickstart application showing the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Please create a demo app and attach it to a ticket in JIRA. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem lies within `AuthenticatedWebSession.signIn(final String username, final String password)`.

This one calls your `authenticate` method and will `destroy()` and `bind()` your session again (this is done to avoid Session fixation).

You can however temporarily store the values you need by overriding `replaceSession()`:

```
// this will be called *after* a successful authenticate
@Override
public void replaceSession() {
    //temp store any values you want to carry over to the new session...
    super.replaceSession();
    //reset them to the session after super.replaceSession();
}
```

Comment: `#replaceSession()` has been used only in 6.19.0. It led to some problems and have been reverted for 6.20.0 (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WICKET-5845).

Comment: Ah okay - I didn't notice that replcaeSession() was introduced in 6.19.0. Thanks for sharing.